# Boot Windows directly through Grub2

Tags: windows, multi-boot, uefi, grub2, boot-manager

I have an UEFI multi-boot system with Windows 7, Windows 10 and OpenSUSE.

Currently when I want to boot Windows, I first need to select Windows Boot Manager in Grub2, it then chainloads the Windows Boot Manager, where I then have to select the Windows version.

However I would like to be able to select the windows version directly in Grub so I don't have two bootloader menus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this by using a separate [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) for each version of Windows. This requires some partition-juggling. In a fresh setup, you'd do something like this:

1. Install the first version of Windows (let's say it's 7). Leave unallocated space on the disk for your later OSes.
2. Using a partition editor that lets you change type codes, change the type codes of the ESP and the Windows partition created in step #1 to other values. For instance, using `gdisk` you might change them both to 8300 (the `gdisk` code for Linux filesystems).
3. Install the second Windows (10).
4. Install your Linux distribution (OpenSUSE).
5. In OpenSUSE, change the type codes you altered in step #2 back to their original values.

Ideally, the scripts that set up GRUB during the Linux installation will correctly detect both of the Windows versions, and you should now be able to boot both versions of Windows. If not, you may be able to customize the GRUB menus manually or change to another boot manager.

Since it sounds like you've already installed everything, you might be able to adapt this procedure by shrinking one partition by a small amount (~550MiB) and creating a second ESP in the freed space. You can then juggle the type codes and use Windows repair utilities to install fresh boot loader(s) for Windows. You'll then need to either re-install GRUB or reset it as the default boot loader and then update the GRUB entries so it can boot either Windows boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can't do this. (If I'm wrong please tell me how to do it. I'd like to know too !).

But you can avoid having to manually enter through the Windows bootlader menu, by setting the timeout to a very short period (0 seconds) so it will automatically continue with the default boot option.
This you can configure in Windows via the properties of "My Computer", Advanced tab, Startup options.
(Or something very similar to that. I don't have a Windows system handy at the moment to check. There are also some minor variations between Windows versions.)